# Initialize Backbone.Marionette.AppRouter after ajax/deferred response

Tags: jquery, ajax, backbone.js, marionette, jquery-deferred

I'm trying to initialize my module's AppRouter in the Controller/Mediator's `start()` function after performing a request and some logic.

The goal here is to make sure that the user meets the app's security/authentication requirements and get updated data for use in completing the actions that will fire when the route is followed.

Basically the page loads, the controller `start()`'s, then an AJAX POST is fired. Depending on the result of the AJAX response, we'll have success and a bunch of json, in which case the route should be followed and then subsequent controller methods fired. (the example code assumes success)

A more in-depth example is in this jsfiddle. Note the `console.log()`'s: http://jsfiddle.net/N5z2R/

I'm using a `$.Deferred()` to determine if the ajax call was completed successfully:

```
var deferred = new $.Deferred();

$.ajax({
    url: '',
    type: 'POST'
}).done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
    // all good, get started
    deferred.resolve();
});

$.when(deferred).then(function() {
    DashboardList.router = new DashboardList.Router({
        controller: DashboardList.controller
    });
});
```

This works fine if I execute the `deferred.resolve();` outside of the AJAX call. In the call, however, the current route is never fired. All subsequent routes work as expected, though.

Am I using deferred wrong?

Am I mistaken in how I understand the route firing to work?

Is this an utterly retarded approach to this problem?

Any answers/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

It looks like my main issue here was loading the AppRouter after `Backbone.history` is started. Updating it like so works:

```
$.when(deferred).then(function(){
    MyApp.DashboardList.start();

    Backbone.history = Backbone.history || new Backbone.History({});
    Backbone.history.start();
});
```

Are there any problems with this I might be overlooking?

Answer (score 0):

The jqXHR objects returned by $.ajax() as of jQuery 1.5 implement the **Promise** interface, giving them all the properties, methods, and behavior of a Promise.

This means that you can use your ajax call with the [deffered](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).

So the code you need should be something similar to:

```
$.when($.ajax('/organizations')).done(function() {
    DashboardList.router = new DashboardList.Router({
        controller: DashboardList.controller
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't think this would provide any benefit here as it seems to just be different syntax accomplishing the same thing. What seems to be the issue (and I could be extremely wrong on all of this) is that initialization of Backbone.history was happening before the AppRouter in question, so the route had been fired before it's handler was bound. No?

Comment: @amsross, it's true that Boti's code is just different syntax, but it's also true that it's a good response to the question "Is this an utterly retarded approach to this problem?" :) If you were to combine your Update code with Boti's suggested structure, then you would end up with something cool. And with very little more thought you can avoid the need for the `$.when()` wrapper.